# android listview: adapter.add(item) ? or adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview

when I use listview, I extends ArrayAdapter and I store the data(one list) in ArrayAdapter, so when data changed,I call:

```
adapter.add(item).;
```

And there is another choice ,store the data in my List and when data changed, called in MyAdapter.java :

```
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

which is the best choice?

Comment: should be `notifyDataSetChanged()` because rather then adding the item to the adapter manually, the data attached to the adapter has changes is notified and the data set should be refresh itself

Answer (score 5):

off course `adapter.add(item);` and after that call `notifyDataSetChanged()` is the better way rather than initialize new adapter and set it again. but it will only works when we are working with a same list and adding or removing some elements. when we are changing the whole list it will not work at that time we should use list.addall(nList).